# C#: Get object from Combobox populated with Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

I populate a ComboBox in WPF with this query:

```
CBKunder.ItemsSource =
    from a in Master.getDC().Kundes
    select a.Kundenavn;
```

In the `selectionChanged` method I want to get the object that is selected. I want to do something like this:

`kunde = (Kunde)CBKunder.SelectedItem;`

But I get an error saying that I can't cast a `String` to a `Kunde`, which is the object I thought was alredy in the ComboBox.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: You're setting `ItemsSource` to be a string, not `Kunde` class instance:

    from a in Master.getDC().Kundes
    select a.Kundenavn;

That's why you can't cast `SelectedItem` to `Kunde`.

Answer (score 3):

Your select seems to be projecting the a.**Kundenavn** into the list. Is there a chance that Kundenavn is indeed a string? This would mean your itemsource is a list of Strings, not 'Kunde'

Give

```
CBKunder.ItemsSource = Master.getDC().Kundes;
```

a go.

Comment: This should be extended with setting `DisplayMemberPath = "Kundenavn"`